# Why does mysql in lamp stack on google cloud vm instance return wrong query results?

Tags: php, mysql, google-cloud-platform, lamp

On my regular host this query return the correct result:

```
$auth_check = $db->raw()
       ->bind( ":username", "email@gmail.com" )
       ->exec( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userType = 'ADMIN' || userType = 'JUNIOR ADMIN' 
AND username = :username " )->fetch();
```

but when I used the same code on a google cloud platform compute VM it gives bizarre results:

Username                     | UserType | Name      | DOB

alainatianastewart@gmail.com | ADMIN    | Leo Admin | 1907-01-01

Is there a reason for this happening? I am using the LAMP stack with a simple website on gcp.

Comment: Normally `OR` is used as `||` can mean "string concatenation" depending on server settings. In this case you should actually be using the simpler `userType IN ('ADMIN', ...)` form.

Comment: Which ORM is this? Normally they have a way of selecting from things like `[ 'ADMIN', 'JUNIOR ADMIN' ]` using ORM functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing here that `x OR y AND z` can be interpreted as `x OR (y AND z)` which will mean "either an admin, or a junior admin with this username" and that's not what you want. You're getting a match on the first condition, which ignores the rest.

This can be fixed by grouping, like `(x OR y) AND z`, but what you really need is:

```sql
WHERE username=:username AND userType IN ('ADMIN', 'JUNIOR ADMIN')
```